# How do I filter out the weekend when I'm using range selector?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash, dashboard

I have this plot-

```
fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scattergl(x=list(df.Date), y=list(df.Measure)), row = 1, col = 1)
    
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis=dict(
        rangeselector=dict(
            buttons=list([
            dict(count=1,
                 label="1m",
                 step="month",
                 stepmode="backward"),
            dict(count=6,
                 label="6m",
                 step="month",
                 stepmode="backward")
            ])
        ),
        rangeslider=dict(
            visible=True
        ),
        type="date"
    ),
    rangebreaks=[
    dict(bounds=["sat", "mon"])
]
)
```

The range breaks work great on the regular charts. Weekends are excluded from my dataset. However, if I click one of the range selectors, then the weekends are no longer excluded. Now, you can see the weekends. The same is true if I set specific hours out of the day for exclusion using the range breaks option. How can I make the range breaks persistent even with the range selector options selected?

Answer (score -1):

Solution proposed here: https://community.plotly.com/t/range-slider-selectors-showing-partial-data-or-failing-to-show-data/38354/2?u=fractalnexus

**Range must be set for the axis** (not the slider). **Solution only works well for plot mode: "lines"** ("markers" or "lines+markers" introduce other issues for the selector, see thread in the link)

Code from link (by Emmanuelle):

```
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis=dict(
        rangeselector=dict(
            buttons=list([
                dict(count=1,
                     label="1M",
                     step="month",
                     stepmode="backward"),
                dict(count=3,
                     label="3M",
                     step="month",
                     stepmode="backward"),
                dict(count=6,
                     label="6M",
                     step="month",
                     stepmode="backward"),
                dict(count=1,
                     label="YTD",
                     step="year",
                     stepmode="todate"),
                dict(count=1,
                     label="1Y",
                     step="year",
                     stepmode="backward"),
                dict(label="All",
                     step="all")
            ])
        ),
        rangeslider=dict(
            visible=True,
        ),
        range=(dates[0], dates[-1]),
        type="date"
    )
)
```

Comment: hey Fractal, welcome to stackoverflow,  it is not recommaned to post comment on the  answers section since it is not the answer.

Comment: @FractalNexus have you found the answer? Or is this still “Not an answer but I can’t comment”?

Comment: Edited the answer to read more like an 'answer'. The fact is that it seems there is no perfect solution for the problem posed by the question, unless someone finds it or the plotly team changes how range selector works. The user who asked the question must try out the solution proposed and see if it works for their particular setup. Hope other users that have the same problem/question find this partial solution here at the least. (Maybe it provides them with a little push to go ask the plotly team for a better solution or workaround themselves) Great question James.